# delay between two threads in a java program

Tags: java, multithreading, delay

In a java program i have two different threads. How to calculate the delay between the execution of the two different threads throughout the program?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the System class's [nanoTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

> Returns the current value of the most
>   precise available system timer, in
>   nanoseconds.

```
 long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 // ... the code being measured ...
 long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

You can also use [currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

> Returns the current time in
>   milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. As the processor skips between the processes using scheduling process. It may take some time for the cpu to come from thread1 to thread2 as there may be some intermediate processes being executed. This may happen the same for all the time slots. I wish to know the delay for moving from thread1 to thread2 for every time slot which are used to execute the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the to threads perform execute the same code, you can calculate the delay using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and compare the time of the first and second thread for each program point you are interested in.